# Geodesics from a specific metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, geodesics

I am currently working through the exercises from "problem book in relativity and gravitation". I am stuck at a particular question. The question: Calculate the time like geodesics of the metric of the form $$\mathrm{d}s^2 = \frac{\mathrm{d}x^2 - \mathrm{d}t^2}{t^2}.$$ The provided answer in the back of the book uses variational principle for the calculation. However I was wondering if it could be done through the geodesic equation and if so how?

Comment: Have you tried doing it with the geodesic equation? If so, please show us your work so we know exactly where you ran into trouble. Otherwise, please try it before asking. Notice that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.